# Show that $G = HK$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

Let $m, n$ be coprime positive integers. Let $G$ be an abelian group
of order $mn$. Let

$$
H = \{ g^m : g \in G \} \quad K = \{ g^n : g \in G \} \\
$$

Show that $G = HK \cong H \times K$

So far I've shown that that $HK \cong H \times K$ but I'm stuck figuring out how to show that $G = HK$. I know that $HK \subseteq G $ but I'm unsure how to prove the other direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: This is part of a bigger question. In the previous parts I've shown that $H, K$ are subgroups of $G$, that any element of $H$ has order dividing $n$, any element of $K$ has order dividing $m$, and $H \cap K = \{ id \}$. I thought I'd include them just in case they are useful.

Comment: It might be worth noting that for *any* group $G$, we have $G=HK$. Indeed, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there exist integers $a,b$ such that $am+bn=1$. Then for all $g\in G$, we have
$$g = g^1 = g^{am+bn} = (g^a)^m (g^b)^n \in HK.$$
However, in general neither $H$ nor $K$ are *subgroups* when $G$ is not abelian.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one fell swoop, given the information you have already.

Use [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798167/show-that-g-hk#comment10204353_4798167). Then $G=HK$.

But $G\cong H\times K$ as an *inner direct product* iff all of:

- $H, K\unlhd G$ (but you have shown $H,K\le G$, and $G$ is abelian);
- $H\cap K=\{e\}$ (shown); and
- $G=HK$.